# JQuery - confirm() not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have an easy script, that works in all browsers, except IE(8, haven't tryed lower versions yet).

```
$('.deleteItemIcon').click(function() {
    var deleteConfirm = confirm('Do you really wanna delete that item?')
    if (!deleteConfirm) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Can you see a reason, why that shouldn't be working, if yes, how to make it work?

Comment: `confirm` should work just fine in IE -- and it does for me.  Your code more or less looks ok (the missing semi-colon shouldn't matter).  I don't suppose you have any IE-specific code that could be overriding the `confirm` function?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is the confirm dialog not displayed at all, or doesn't it return `true` when OK is clicked?

Answer (score 4):

Just curious, to those who this code does not work for... are you using IETester? I had several problems with IE8 (when using IETester) and once I actually took the 20 minutes to upgrade to ie8 I found the code worked... Just a thought. Another note, I went through and made sure I was fully updated with IETester and still had the problems. Confirms and Alerts were not working properly (if at all...) for ie8.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the missing semi colon after the confirm?

Why not also just change it to

```
return confirm('Do you really wanna delete that item?');
```

Comment: The missing semi-colon shouldn't matter because line-breaks are permitted to terminate statements in JavaScript.  It is Best Practice™ to use semi-colons though.

Comment: tryed it and doesnt work for me, there is nothing more going on on the page .. I'm confused, why it doesn't work.

Comment: In that case you need to be more specific about what doesn't work, as others have asked... Can you create a simple test harness that fails for you and paste the entire html?

Comment: tested the code Matt posted and it doesn't work either, so .. =/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.deleteItemIcon').click(function() {
return confirm('Do you really wanna delete that');
});
```

try it like this

you don't need to put your confirm in a variable and check it after to return false. Confirm already returns `true` or `false` so you can simply return the result of your `confirm()`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with IE 9.0.39 and noticed that using 
`console.log("")`
was the problem.

Once I commented out that line of code, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your scope.

You've got to use

`var confirmed = window.confirm('Do you really wanna delete that item?');`

It's working for me in firefox now; I don't know about IE though.

Answer (score 0):

My HTML:

```
<a href="/default.aspx?mode=Reset" id="rstPrtlts">Reset to default layout</a>
```

This works in Chrome but not IE:

```
$('#rstPrtlts').click( function() {return confirm('This will reset your widgets on the homepage. Are you sure?');});
```

However I do have very similar code on page that does work. It is worth noting the code I am referring to is from a .js file loaded from a static server.

This does work on both Chrome and IE:

```
$('#rstPrtlts').click( function(e) {if(confirm('This will reset your widgets on the homepage. Are you sure?')) { window.location = e.currentTarget.href;}});
```

No idea why the first code wouldn't work. I've heard several reasons, IE blocks functions that always return false, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and window.confirm("Text") worked for me in IE ,Crome and Firefox.